Numerical coordinate for column chart X axis
I often create column charts with a scatterplot overlay to show individual points. However, I have to guess at the x values for the scatterplot. My formula for the x values is =(rand()/a) + b, where a is a divisor for the random and b is an index to ensure the points lie within a specific column
Is there a reference that explains the x coordinates for the x positions and widths of the columns in numeric terms? For example, what would a useful a and list of b's be if I had a column chart that had two groups of four columns, to wit:


It would be useful to see the data for your chart and an image of the expected result.

Does that mean nobody knows how Excel assigns coordinate values to columns?

Update:
You asked if there's any way to get coordinates of columns. Here's some of the answer, assuming there is only one chart and appears on its own sheet. We'll call that chart Chart1. Below are the VBA objects & properties. Note that the origin of the chart's chart area is 0, 0. The property "Left" is the lower left corner of a column. "Top" is the upper right corner. These values are in relation to the origin of the chart area; values are Double.
Chart area size:
width: Chart1.ChartArea.Width

height: Chart1.ChartArea.Height

Assuming two series of data where columns are adjacent.
First series:
left:  Chart1.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Left

top: Chart1.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Top

Column width:
Chart1.SeriesCollection(2).Points(1).Left -Chart1.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Left

I hope this gets you on the right road.
Previously:
The best I can suggest is to look at the ChartObject, along with Points object and Point object. Those & a whole bunch of VBA you'll get how far from the left side of a chart a column's left edge is. Or the column's center with a bit more work.
Hope you like working in VBA.
